# Why am I getting two copies of an Injectable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 9 monorepository with a library and an app. The library has a service (`@Injectable()`) which is referenced in components and services library and other services in the app. I can't figure out why classes in the library and the app appear to have different instances of the same `@Injectable`. The respective sources look something like this:

apps/myapp/src/app/services/app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService } from '@lib/services';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(public libSvc: SomeService) { }
}
```

libs/mylib/src/lib/services/some.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService { }
```

apps/myapp/src/app/components/some.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AppService } from '@app/services';
import { SomeService } from '@lib/services';

@Component()
export class SomeComponent {

  public somevar: string;

  constructor(
    public appSvc: AppService,
    public libSvc: SomeService
  ) { }

  someMethod() {
    if (this.appSvc.libSvc !== this.libSvc) {
      console.log('Services are different');
    }
  }
}
```

where `apps/myapp/tsconfig.app.json` contains

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["../../../libs/mylib/src/lib/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

and `libs/mylib/tsconfig.lib.json` contains

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@lib/*": ["lib/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

When `someMethod` is called, "Services are different" is printed to the console. It looks like there are two instances of the `Injectable` instead of a single instance like I expected. Instance variables in the two have different values, i.e. if I set `AppService.libSvc.somevar` to a value in `AppService`, the value isn't set in `SomeService.somevar`, and vice versa. What's happening here?

Comment: Do you provide the service in more than one place? If you set `providedIn: 'root'`, and do not include it in any other `providers` list, it should be a [singleton](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).

Comment: I've added an explicit providedIn: 'root' to the service, and am still getting the same behavior. Any ideas? Is the fact that the lib and the app are getting to the service via a different path in tsconfig relevant?

Comment: Is the service included in another `providers` list in your application?

Comment: AppService is included in the providers list of a module in the app, and SomeService is included in the providers list of a module in the library, but nowhere else.

Comment: Try removing `AppService` from the providers list of the module.

Comment: As expected, I get "NullInjectorError: No provider for AppService!"

Comment: What Angular version are you using? For Angular 6+, providing the service in root should be enough. See [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-a-service).

Comment: Okay, this is interesting. When I remove SomeService from the list of providers in the app in the library, everything works as expected. The implication is that, even though I'm not including it in a list of providers elsewhere (in the app) it's somehow ending up there because something that uses it is in the list of providers. So... what do I do about it?